# How to place Checkboxes with ListView (Android)

Tags: java, android

I was following the ListView official tutorial - [url]http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html[/url], because I get the entries dinamically through a webservice.

Problem is, I want to place checkboxes at it. I have this

(aux (String [] aux) is previously and correctly fullfilled before this)

```
//setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.lista, aux));
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<CheckBox>(this,R.layout.row, convertToListItem(aux)));

        //ListView lv = getListView();
        //lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

And I think the problem is on my row.xml

```
<CheckBox xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="14sp" android:typeface="normal" android:textStyle="normal"

    android:layout_weight="0" android:layout_gravity="left" />
```

or in this function

```
private List<CheckBox> convertToListItem(String[] aux2){

        List<CheckBox> result = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();  
        ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();

        for (String text : aux2){
            CheckBox temp = new CheckBox(this);
            temp.append(text);
            temp.setText(text,BufferType.NORMAL);
            result.add(temp);
            boxes.add(temp);

        }

        return result;
```

What happens is: it appears the checkbox, but in front instead the right text it appears "android.widget.Checkbox@...."

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement your own Adapter extending ArrayAdapter and put a TextView in your row.xml

Then you must handle your view from getView() method.

Let me know if this helps, if not, please can you add more info about what you need/want a more code for sure.